# PHP and tags in a DB

Tags: php

I'm submitting tags into a DB like tag1,tag2,tag3. How would I go about splitting them so i could pharse them into links and then query the DB for other submissions that use those tags?

Comment: are you using MySQL database? what is the original input that you want to split?

Comment: Yes, MySQL. Right now the data is submitted via a textbox in the format of tag1,tag2,tag3

Answer (score 4):

You should probably keep tags in a separate table, and link them to the record using a field containing the record's id.

Most one to many relationships within a database call for separate tables. Comma separated values go against what makes databases so great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure to understand but if you want to parse your tag string you can use:

```
<?php 
  str=" tag1, tag2, tag3 "; 
  $array = explode(', ', trim(str)); 
?>
```

You'll normally get the a array with the 3 tag inside.

But you should insert tag one by one in another table a make reference on them.

Comment: Minor quibble, but you should trim after explode, not explode after trim. There may be any number of spaces before/after commas. I use `array_map('trim', explode(',', strtolower($str)))`

Answer (score 0):

A very simple but very hackey approach would be to enter your tags with beginning and trailing commas so `,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,` because then you can get tag2 by querying for `where tag LIKE '%,tag2,%'` Granted this is slow and there are way more advanced ways to do this via 1:many relationships.  If you want to make tags into links I would look into a structure where 1 table has posts and one table has tags.  http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html has a few table structures and explanations on how this works.